# NetBeans "Servers" menu item "Refresh" does what?

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, netbeans-8

I can find no documentation for this "Refresh" menu item in NetBeans 8.

NetBeans 8.1 > "Services" (panel) > Servers (list) > Refresh (context menu)

[image: Screenshot of NetBeans Services panel]

Answer (score 0):

It refreshes the list of deployments. You see the same Refresh call if you open the Tomcat element and click on "Web Applications".